# Depending on a non-published plugin with freezed generated files

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-freezed

In my project, I am using the flutter_google_places_sdk but I needed to modify certain things in its interface, so I forked the repository in Github, and I added a dependency override in my `pubspec.yaml` to point to my own Github repository for this specific dependency.

The problem is that this package uses freezed a lot to generate some files, and when I run `flutter pub run build_runner build` in my project, it doesn't seem to do anything for dependencies.

I even tried to add dependencies to `freezed` and `freezed_annotation` in my own project, hoping that it would signal `build_runner` to look for annotations in dependencies too, but it doesn't work either.

I am guessing that when you publish a package, it publishes generated files as well, but I don't want to publish this plugin, just use it for myself. What is the proper way to integrate this kind of dependency.

NB: After adding freezed-generated files to my fork of `flutter_google_places_sdk` as suggested by the chosen solution, I still had the following exception at runtime when calling `fetchPlace`, which I did not modify whatsoever, so it seems there might be an issue with the generated files.

```
flutter: FlutterGooglePlacesSdk::call error: type '_Map<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
#0      _$$_PlaceFromJson.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_google_places_sdk_platform_interface/src/types/place.g.dart:12:52)
#1      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:415:31)
#2      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:344:26)
#3      new _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:27)
#4      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
#5      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:52:28)
#6      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:214:7)
#7      _$$_PlaceFromJson (package:flutter_google_places_sdk_platform_interface/src/types/place.g.dart:13:12)
#8      new _$_Place.fromJson (package:flutter_google_places_sdk_platform_interface/src/types/place.freezed.dart:391:7)
#9      _$PlaceFromJson (package:flutter_google_places_sdk_plat<…>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to commit auto generated code in you forked repository by avoid in `.gitignore`.
I created PR [here](https://github.com/sarbogast/flutter_google_places_sdk/pull/1) for your forked repo.

You can generate a code by running command `flutter pub run build_runner build` in that `flutter_google_places_sdk_platform_interface` folder manually.

Comment: Now my project compiles, but at runtime, I'm getting a weird error inside of one of the generated files (`place.g.dart`): `Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast`.

Comment: Surprise, can you add stacktrace

Comment: I added the stacktrace to the question